# Threading in Python not working as expected

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to process my files in a directory using threading.Being new to threads i expected each thread to process a file separately.But the program is waiting until one file has been processed.The program starts the thread using  `t.start()` and waits for it to finish to print the message in the next line which is

```
print 'Started....' + fieldType +' proccessing'
```

And then only start another thread

Here is a part of the python code

```
while(1):
for filename in os.listdir(inputFileDirectory):
    filePath = inputFileDirectory + '/' + filename
    f1 = open(filePath,'rb')
    try:
        reader  = csv.reader(f1)
        data = [l for l in reader]
        headerRow =  data[0]
        fieldType = headerRow[1]
        t = Thread(target=ProcessFile(fieldType,filePath,data))
        t.start()

        print 'Started....' + fieldType +' proccessing'

        threads.append(t)

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()

        print "Complete."
    finally:
        f1.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

You start a thread, then put it into a list and immediately join all threads in that list, therefore you can always have one active thread in that list.

You need to move

```
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

out of your for loop.

Comment: i tried moving it out of the loop but still its not printing the "Started" message

Comment: are you sure `ProcessFile(...)` isn't blocking?

Comment: Its actually running....its a loop in that ProcessFile....i tried printing to check if its running and its is...

Answer (score 1):

Show us the code of `ProcessFile`. I think the problem is you're not passing it to `Thread` constructor as a function reference (`target=ProcessFile`), but calling it and then passing whatever it returns to `Thread()`.

If I'm right, instead you should do

```
t = Thread(target=ProcessFile, args=(fieldType, filePath, data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Join`, that's why it's waiting.

> join([time]): The join() waits for threads to terminate.

Think of `Join` as a sync, when do you want to sync your threads?

If you want for example `N` threads to process, when they are done you want to continue with your software then use join after the threads are done.

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 issues my piece of code

One issue is as pointed by @mata i need to move

```
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

out of the for loop

And the second issue was as pointed by @justinas

```
t = Thread(target=ProcessFile(fieldType,filePath,data))
```

should be

```
t = Thread(target=ProcessFile, args=(fieldType, filePath, data))
```